# Is Event TIMER always dispatched before TIMER_COMPLETE?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

Is flash.utils.Timer object's event TIMER always dispatched before TIMER_COMPLETE?

During the 2nd event, I am nullifying stuff that are required during the 1st event; so their order is of prime importance. I checked the docs and there is no guarantee for their dispatching order.

In tests I've done it seems that this is the case, but I don't want to distribute publicly software without confirming first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid this problem by using TimerEvent.TIMER only:

```
private function onTimer(event:TimerEvent)
{
    // ...

    if (timer.currentCount == timer.repeatCount) {
        // timer is complete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive this is the case, since the code seems to be in the player itself I don't think you can get at the source to get a legitimate confirmation, however I have always seen this to be the case myself and from how the docs read it sounds as though a TIMER event would always be dispatched before the complete event

timerComplete
Dispatched whenever it has completed the number of requests set by Timer.repeatCount.

timer
Dispatched whenever a Timer object reaches an interval specified according to the Timer.delay property.

So I imagine the timerComplete is dispatched after it receives enough timer events that the currentCount equals the repeat count then a timerComplete is dispatched, however without being able to look at the code it's  impossible for anyone to completely confirm this.  Possibly you could look at the Gnash source to see how it's handled by that implementation of the player, but it's not necessarily the same in the normal Flash Player.